# Implement a complicated/long formula using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a small program that will calculate the amount of time it will take to pay of a credit card and I found [this equation online](http://www.businessinsider.com.au/11-personal-finance-equations-you-need-to-know-2012-7?op=1#credit-card-equation-11):

[image]

This is what I have so far (just trying to get the equation to work with dummy data before I try a function). However I keep getting errors to do with end of input and unexpected (. Would love some help if people get the chance. Thanks!

```
card_length = ((0.06/365)/30) * ((log(1+(14000/200)(1-(1+0.06)^30)))/log(1+0.06))
```

Comment: The formula is quite complicated for  a one liner; try breaking into many variables and packing individual parts in methods in a class. It will help you test it out faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula wasn't well explained nor it had any example values to test the solution. But anyways, try this:

```
class CreditCard
  def initialize(balance: b, monthly_payment: m, annual_interest_rate: a)
    @balance = balance
    @monthly_payment = monthly_payment
    @annual_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate
  end

  def how_long
    (-1 / 30) * (numerator / denominator)
  end

  def daily_interest_rate
    @annual_interest_rate / 365
  end

  def b_by_p
    @balance / @monthly_payment
  end

  def one_plus_i
    1 + daily_interest_rate
  end

  def numerator
    Math.log(1 + b_by_p * (1 - (one_plus_i)**30))
  end

  def denominator
    Math.log one_plus_i
  end
end

CreditCard.new(balance: 1500, monthly_payment: 500, annual_interest_rate: 0.10).how_long # => 91.50823668064119
```

Comment: Wow thanks for writing all that out! I actually got it to work using another formula as well (after reading your method). Yours works great - the only thing is it needs to divide by 30 to get to months otherwise its in days. Again thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Sure, pal! I learned Ruby through the answers and resources of many out there. Thought I would give some of it back :) .. Best wishes!

Comment: This is a great answer. People should encapsulate logic in classes more; it's so easy to do in Ruby. (the method `one_plus_i` is a bit overkill though)

Comment: I know, but `one_plus_i` was used as the internal variable was quite long and would have made an already complicated line look more noisy to follow. And since it was used twice I felt it will read better.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to change your `log` method calls to `Math.log` calls. Also, you are missing a multiplication operator in the second part, and powers in Ruby are calculated with `**`, so:

```
card_length = ((0.06/365)/30) * ((Math.log(1+(14000/200)*(1-(1+0.06)**30)))/Math.log(1+0.06))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I tried what you said but now keep getting this error `Numerical argument is out of domain - "log"`

Comment: This is because of the values you are using in the equation. This return a negative number: `1+(14000/200)*(1-(1+0.06)**30)`, which is out of the domain of the `Math.log` method. Change those values to get a positive number (or 0)